# Js extract information from a json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I have the following json that is quite complex and detailed.

I need to extrapolate information (text) from the json only if the `resource-id` contains the following text `"com.shazam.android:id/"` and if it contains the following props (`["title", "subtitle", "datetime"]`).

If last element does not contain a `datetime` then `resorceIdFinal` is not inserted.

Below is an example json I want to get.

Here you can find the json I use, I couldn't insert it here due to character space.

Link: https://pastebin.com/raw/hFLmP2T8

```js
const check = (obj, keys) => !keys.some((el) => !obj.hasOwnProperty(el));

const isObjectEmpty = (objectName) => {
  return (
    objectName &&
    Object.keys(objectName).length === 0 &&
    objectName.constructor === Object
  );
};

const getChildren = (el, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal) => {
  var arr = [];

  el.forEach((el) => {
    let resorceId = getResorceId(el.attributes, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal);
    if(!isObjectEmpty(resorceId)) arr.push(resorceId);   
    //console.log(arr);
    getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal);
  });
  
  return arr;
};


const getResorceId = (el, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal) => {
  var o = {};
  if (el["resource-id"] !== undefined) {
    var resorceId = el["resource-id"].replace(replaceText, "");
    if (props.includes(resorceId)) {
      o = { [resorceId]: el.text };
    }
  }
  return o;
};

function readPro(json, replaceText, props, filterA, resorceIdFinal) {
  var arr = [];

  json.forEach((el) => {
    arr.push(getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal));
  });
  
  console.log(arr)

  filtered = arr.filter(
    ((s) => (o) =>
      ((k) => !s.has(k) && s.add(k))(filterA.map((k) => o[k]).join("|")))(
        new Set()
      )
  );

  return filtered;
}


var res = readPro(
  a.children,
  "com.shazam.android:id/",
  ["title", "subtitle", "datetime"],
  ["title", "subtitle"],
  "datetime"
);

console.log(res);
```

Json result I would like to get:

```json
[
   {
        "title": "Believe",
        "subtitle": "Chuther",
        "datetime": "12 giu, 16:42"
   },
   {
        "title": "시작 (Inst.)",
        "subtitle": "Gaho",
        "datetime": "12 giu, 16:42"
   },
   {
        "title": "Give It Up",
        "subtitle": "KC and the Sunshine Band",
        "datetime": "12 giu, 16:41"
   },
   {
        "title": "GRAVITY",
        "subtitle": "Jong Ho",
        "datetime": "12 giu, 16:41"
    }
]
```

Can you give me a hand?

Edit:

```js
const isObjectEmpty = (objectName) =>
(
  objectName &&
  Object.keys(objectName).length === 0 &&
  objectName.constructor === Object
);


const getResorceId = (el, replaceText, props, value) => {
  if (el["resource-id"] !== undefined) {
    var resorceId = el["resource-id"].replace(replaceText, "");
    if (props.includes(resorceId)) {
      return { [resorceId]: el[value] };
    }
  }
  return {};
};

const getChildren = (el, replaceText, props, value) => {
  var arr = [];
  el.forEach((el) => {
    let resorceId = getResorceId(el.attributes, replaceText, props, value);
    var o = {}
    if (!isObjectEmpty(resorceId)) {
      arr.push(resorceId);
      for (const [_, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
        for (const [key, value2] of Object.entries(value))
          o[key] = value2
      }
      arr = [o]
    }

    arr.push(...getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, value));
  });

  //console.log(arr.length, arr)
  //if(arr.length === 1 && !Object.hasOwn(...arr, resorceIdFinal)) arr = []

  return arr
};

function readPro(json, replaceText, props, filterA, value) {
  var arr = [];
  json.forEach((el) => {
    arr.push(...getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, value));
  });

  filtered = arr.filter(
    ((s) => (o) =>
      ((k) => !s.has(k) && s.add(k))(filterA.map((k) => o[k]).join("|")))(
        new Set()
      )
  );

  return filtered;
}

var rA = readPro(
  a.children,
  "com.shazam.android:id/",
  ["title", "subtitle", "datetime"],
  ["title", "subtitle"],
  "text"
);
```

Comment: You don't want to use JSON.parse?

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Json parse for what?
The problem is the structure is so nested, that there is something I'm doing wrong or forgetting.

Comment: When you debug, which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?  What are the observed runtime values used in that operation?  What is the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David: I get an empty array.
The final result can be found in the post at the end.

The problem I think is the recursive calls which should return something, but I'm doing something wrong in the code I wrote.

Comment: After examining your pastebin file I do see the structure of this. Apparently you want to build a playlist of some kind from the data embedded in that json, which likely is a playlist in of self. I think the best way to solve this is to scan linearly. There is a definite pattern enabling you to do so.

Comment: @GetSet: It's not exactly linear, you can only get a lot of information through recursion.
In fact the information I need to retrieve is around the end of the tree.

If you give me a code example, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Paul, no claims on the data being linear but rather scanning it (line by line) as if it were a flat array would work because of a pattern that occurs: specifically, that  "text" attributes containing *subtitle* and *datetime* fall in order (even if spaced apart) after lines containing *title*.

Comment: @GetSet: Ok, it seems to work.
The problem compared to the algorithm I wrote, is slower.
The time your script took: 2,398ms

What I currently tried to write takes: 0.701ms.

Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Paul That is a significant time difference.

Answer (score 1):

This function recursively calls itself, but ignores the result of that call:

```
const getChildren = (el, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal) => {
  var arr = [];

  el.forEach((el) => {
    let resorceId = getResorceId(el.attributes, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal);
    if(!isObjectEmpty(resorceId)) arr.push(resorceId);   
    //console.log(arr);
    getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal);
  });
  
  return arr;
};
```

Nothing is ever done with the return value of `getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal)`.  Perhaps the intent was to add that result to the `arr` array?:

```
const getChildren = (el, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal) => {
  var arr = [];

  el.forEach((el) => {
    let resorceId = getResorceId(el.attributes, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal);
    if(!isObjectEmpty(resorceId)) arr.push(resorceId);   
    //console.log(arr);
    arr.push(...getChildren(el.children, replaceText, props, resorceIdFinal));
  });
  
  return arr;
};
```

---

Note that there is a lot of code here, and this answer makes no guarantee that this is the *only* problem in the code shown.  But it at least appears to be the most relevant to the problem described.  You are encouraged to [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) to narrow down any additional problems, asking a separate question if any are found.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I managed to get it working, I would like to make it simpler and cleaner. If you have the opportunity you can take a look at it. Here is the json file it was tested with: pastebin.com/raw/jmHMnfvg

Answer (score 1):

In continuation from comments, provided your requirements haven't changed significantly, the data to be extracted can be done so by treating the json string on a "line by line" basis.

From looking at the desired output and the source json, it is the `text` attributes in the json structure that then become *title, subtitle, and datetime*. As such, when any attribute named `text` comes along (linearly), then the algorithm saves it as being the last encountered. Next when a desired sentinel is encountered, each of these:

```
com.shazam.android:id/title
com.shazam.android:id/subtitle
com.shazam.android:id/datetime
```

... The previously (or last) saved `text` attribute is assigned to be that property.
When *datetime* is recorded, this is assumed to be the end of the record and it is pushed onto an array so that the next record if any can then be progressively built in the same fashion.

The rest is explained by way the code itself and code comments.

This is a working example. Copy and paste the json into the textarea then click the button. The json must be complete because it tries to parse it first, then stringifies so that its properly separated into lines. These steps can be commented out when you already know the input is separated into lines.

```js
function extract( input_json ) {    
        
    // In the event that the source json is not already broken into lines:
    try {
        let _parsed = JSON.parse( input_json );
        input_json = JSON.stringify(_parsed , null, 1);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error parsing json");
        return false;
    }
    
    
    // Turn into an array, one line per index
    
    let json_lines = input_json.split("\n");
    
    
    // Now onto a linear scan/search to gather the pertinent data
    
    let output = []; // this will hold the end result
    
    let last_passed_text = ''; // this will be the last "text" attribute's value encountered
    
    
    let current_record = {}; // this will hold the current record being built progressively
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < json_lines.length; i++) {
        
        let textPos = json_lines[i].indexOf('"text"');
        
        if ( textPos > -1) {
        
            let _firstColon = json_lines[i].indexOf(":");
            
            if (_firstColon > textPos) {
        
            // split by colon since `"text" :`  indicates definition desired
            
                let relevantPart = json_lines[i].substring( _firstColon + 1).trim(); // characters after colon to end of string, trimmed
            
            try {
                relevantPart = decodeURIComponent( relevantPart ); // just in case
            }
            catch {}
            
                // assume that characters after colon behave as `"abcdef",` and if not it doesn't matter, e.g. boolean values
                
                let token = relevantPart.substring(1,relevantPart.length-2); // get value between the assumed double quotes, -2 because of trailing comma, if any
                
                last_passed_text = token.toString(); // de-ref
                
                // console.log("last_passed_text",last_passed_text);
                
            }
        }
        
        if ( json_lines[i].indexOf("resource-id") > -1) {
            
            
            
            if ( json_lines[i].indexOf("com.shazam.android:id/title") > -1) {
                
                // presence of title always indicates where to start collecting
                
                current_record = {};
                current_record.title = last_passed_text.toString(); // de-ref
                
                //console.log("title", current_record.title);
                
                // console.log( json_lines[i], last_passed_text );
                
                
            }
            else if ( json_lines[i].indexOf("com.shazam.android:id/subtitle") > -1) {
                current_record.subtitle = last_passed_text.toString(); // de-ref
                
                // console.log( json_lines[i], last_passed_text );
            }
            else if ( json_lines[i].indexOf("com.shazam.android:id/datetime") > -1) {
                current_record.datetime = last_passed_text.toString(); // de-ref
                
                // presence of datetime always indicates where to end collecting
                
                output.push( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( current_record )) );
                
                // console.log( json_lines[i], last_passed_text );
                
                
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    
    // console.log(output);
    
    return output;
}
```

```html
Paste json here: (input)<br>
<textarea id="input-json" rows=15 cols=50></textarea>
<hr>
<button type="button" onclick="
    console.log( 
        extract( 
            document.getElementById('input-json').value
        ) 
    );">Extract To Console</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried your code with another json generated the same way, I get the following error: `{
   "message": "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed",
   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
   "lineno": 62,
   "colno": 32
} ` Here is the json file it was tested with: https://pastebin.com/raw/jmHMnfvg

Comment: @Paul I'll try it now. Ok I see it. Has to do with the decodeURIComponent failing. The fix is to wrap it in a try catch. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a solution, although there's still something to fix. If you want to take a look at it, you can look at edit.

Comment: There are probably quite a few more things to fix, or at least as precautions: (1) the code makes the assumption that *title, subtitle, datetime* will come in that order. If they always do, then no issues. (2) If the code doesn't encounter a datetime it wont push the record. ... But these are non issues if the source json follows the pattern.

Comment: The pattern is the same, they were generated the same way.
I don't understand why your code doesn't work with other json.

Comment: I made some edits on it (here). Have you re-ran it since the decodeURIComponent exception? I put that in a try/catch. What other errors did you encounter?